# PHP Proxy - Uploading Files with cURL

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, curl, laravel

I'm currently building an application written in AngularJS with a Laravel based API for the backend, data is passed via a simple PHP proxy to keep my API key secure(ish).

For POST requests the proxy simply `json_decode` PHPs input stream (php://input) as Angular serialises POST data to JSON, passes it through `http_build_query` then forwards it via cURL to the API - so far, it's been working flawlessly.

I've managed to get the file over to the proxy - however, as it's sent with `multipart/form-data` headers, it's only available in `$_FILES` and not the input stream.

Relevant snippets from the proxy below:

```
function curlRequest($url, $post = false, $data = null)
{
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  if($post == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
  }

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($ch);
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$data['api_key'] = API_KEY;

// File data available here!
var_dump($_FILES);

$result = curlRequest(URL, true, $data);
```

The problem I'm having, I'm unsure how to correctly POST the file to the API endpoint once I've got it in `$_FILES`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see `$_FILES` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may send files over as well :

```
$data = json_decode(array_merge($_REQUEST, $_FILES));
$data['api_key'] = API_KEY;

// File data available here!
var_dump($_FILES);

$result = curlRequest(URL, true, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful. 

In the end I wrote a test for 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' headers and, if true, ran `array_merge($data, $_POST, $_FILES)` - as $_POST contains any strings submitted with multipart/form-data headers.